# t-sql find min value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I find *the minimum value among the values ​​not filled or not exists*

for example

```
001  
002  
003
013
015
```

result must return 004

select min

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @T table(Number int)

insert into @T values (1),(2),(3),(13),(15)

select top 1 Number + 1
from @T
where Number + 1 not in (select Number from @T)
order by Number
```

**Update:**

A version using char(3) zero padded.

```
declare @T table(ID char(3))

insert into @T values ('001'),('002'),('003'),('013'),('015')

select top 1 right(1001 + Id, 3)
from @T
where Id + 1 not in (select Id from @T)
order by Id
```

Comment: This usually works quite well, but how would this work if `009` was stored as a `CHAR(3)`? the leading zeroes in the question makes me think it's a `CHAR` not `INT` field. Just wondering :)

Comment: @Seph - Added a version with char(3) as data type. No difference really except for the result value and the fact that there are a bunch of implicit type conversions and it will not use any index on `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your sequence in the table YourNumbersTable
Try this (SQL Server 2005+):

```
declare @min int, @max int
select @min = MIN(Id), @max = MAX(Id) from YourNumbersTable

;WITH numbers(id) as
(
    SELECT @min id
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT id+1
    FROM numbers
    WHERE id <= @max
)

SELECT MIN(Numbers.id)
FROM Numbers
     LEFT JOIN YourNumbersTable ON Numbers.Id = YourNumbersTable.Id
WHERE YourNumbersTable.Id IS NULL
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (no joins, no rec-cte)

```
declare @T table(n int)

insert into @T values (1),(2),(3),(13),(15)


select max(n)+1 from (
  select *,l=n-row_number() over(order by n)  
    from (
      select n from @T
      union
      select 0 -- what about 0 ??
    ) as s
) as a
where l=-1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [what @szauri has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674998/297408), but without aggregating:

```
;
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT n, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)
  FROM @T
)
SELECT TOP 1 r
FROM ranked
WHERE n <> r
ORDER BY n
```

Note: Both @szauri's and my solutions require SQL Server 2005 or later version.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I have an alternative solution. It can be slower on wide number ranges because of the loop in it.

```
-- prepare a table to have your example 
declare @ref table (id int)
insert into @ref (id) values (1), (2), (3), (13), (15)

-- this will return 1
select min(id) from @ref

-- magic happens here
declare @i int, @max int, @returnValue int
select @i = min(id), @max = max(id) from @ref
declare @tmp table (id int)
while @i <= @max
    begin
    insert into @tmp (id) values (@i)
    set @i = @i + 1
    end

select @returnValue = min(t.id) 
    from @tmp t left outer join @ref r on t.id = r.id
    where r.id is null

-- this will return 4
select @returnValue
```